# Manually getting SpriteKit sibling order

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit, if some nodes share the same `zPosition`, then the nodes are rendered in the order they were added to the scene so that the latest node added will be on top of the other ones *(as long as the `ignoresSiblingOrder` scene property is set to false)*.

I am wondering if there is a way to know the order in which SpriteKit is going to render the nodes that share the same `zPosition`, so that I can give then an explicit zPosition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Premise

When you add a child to an `SKNode` it gets added at the end of the `children` array property. (At least this what I found running a few tests).

### Solution

So you can scroll all the children of a given node and group them by `zPosition`. You'll get a dictionary where the `key` is the `zPosition` and the `value` is an ordered list of nodes (from the oldest insertion to the most recent).

### Extension

```
extension SKNode {
    func childrenByZPosition() -> [CGFloat:[SKNode]] {
        return children.reduce([CGFloat:[SKNode]]()) { (var accumulator, node) -> [CGFloat:[SKNode]] in
            var list = accumulator[node.zPosition] ?? [SKNode]()
            list.append(node)
            accumulator[node.zPosition] = list
            return accumulator
        }
    }
}
```

### Test

```
class Foo: SKNode {
    let num: Int

    init(num: Int) {
        self.num = num
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var description: String { return num.description }
}

let scene = SKScene()
let node0 = Foo(num: 0)
node0.zPosition = 1
let node1 = Foo(num: 1)
let node2 = Foo(num: 2)
node2.zPosition = 1
let node3 = Foo(num: 3)
let node4 = Foo(num: 4)

scene.addChild(node0)
scene.addChild(node1)
scene.addChild(node2)
scene.addChild(node3)
scene.addChild(node4)
```

Now you can group the children by `zPosition`

```
let dict = scene.childrenByZPosition()
dict[0] // [1, 3, 4]
dict[1] // [0, 2]
```